# Understanding and constructing the physical states of a $\mathcal{N}=2$ long massive vector multiplet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, supersymmetry, fermions

How do I construct the physical states of a $\mathcal{N} = 2$ *long* massive *V-plet*?

I have seen that it is meant to be like the image below, but I don't understand how.

[image]

I also know that when it doesn't saturate the BPS bound, by acting with fermionic creation operators on a Clifford vacuum of spin $s = 0$, the diagram is:

[image]

**How was the first plot put together, and how does the second one relate to it?**

**How can I obtain the bosonic and fermionic degrees of freedom based on these?**

Comment: Are you looking for a good reference or for an explanation here as an answer to the question?

Comment: Regarding the diagrams, I am looking for an explanation of how to build such diagrams. I have the answers to the questions, but my aim is to understand why they are like this.

Regarding the bosonic and fermionic degrees of freedom, I don't seem to find anything in my notes or online that relates them to these diagrams so an input on this would be great too. 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am a bit busy to provide a full-fledged answer and to be honest that there are experts in this site to address your question. I think that this is a helpful resource -at least to get you started somehow- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.00870.pdf Elli is discussing $\mathcal{N}=2$ superconformal symmetry and the relevant part to your question is section 5. I hope that this is a good starting point. If there are no answers I will try to write something later as good as I can.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Somewhat [linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68027/cal-n-1-vs-cal-n-2-supermultiplets/68031#68031).